# How do I get all samplers response times in the ResponseTimesOverTime of Graph Generator

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

can someone guide me how to achieve the below.
Q: How do I get all samplers response times in the ResponseTimesOverTime of Graph Generator

See for ex : From the below screenshot NE_EDM_TC has 7 pass counts.But in the ResponseTimesOverTime graph generated using Graph Generator showing only 5 pass counts. I would like to see all the 7 pass counts in the graph.

How do i achieve this? Please advise me!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
Thanks,
Rajani

Comment: Actually there are 7 data points in the graph. The values 497,517,560, and 757 are somehow not clearly visible due to it granularity. Four values are in 50Ks range and other four values are in 500+ ms. 

To validate, right click on the graph and export it to CSV. 
Open the CSV file, you could see all the data points.

Please let me know if this works :)

Comment: @Naveen,It's png when i rich click it's not gibing me any options to save as CSV.This graph is generated from jc@gc Graph Generator.

Comment: Can you try exporting both CSV and PNG in graph listener? This will help you to validate. Thanks!

Comment: @Naveen, CSV shows 8 data points. Screenshot has been attached to the original post.

Comment: Then there is nothing wrong in the graph. Due to it granularity the data points are merged which you cannot see them.

Comment: Try plotting the same data in Excel using the same Y axis interval. You will not be able to see all the data points.

Comment: @Naveen, I know there is nothing wrong the graph, what I am trying to see/get  is there any option to see all the data points in the graph!

Comment: I am checking again. But failed one usually do not plot in the graph by default.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139888/discussion-between-naveenkumar-namachivayam-and-rpagadala).